# Conexion y mostrar tabla de base de datos

Tags: javascript, html, base-de-datos, nodejs

Mi duda es si se puede conectar, visualizar y editar a una base de datos SIN PHP, ya que estoy trabajando con una aplicación y necesito visualizar los datos de la DB de una tabla de "Usuarios" pero en esa tabla también tengo que poder agregar nuevos usuarios, eliminar y editar los usuarios nuevos y ya existentes.

Este es el código que llevo al momento en JS:

```
var ClauBal=(()=>{
var mysql      = require('mysql2');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'www.lapaginaquetienelaDB.com',
  user     : 'usuarioparaingresaralaDB',
  password : 'PASSWORD',
  database : 'DBdondeestalatablaquequierovisualizar'
});

return{
conexion:()=>{
  connection.connect();
   connection.query('SELECT * from Usuarios', function(err, rows, fields) {
     if (!err){
       console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
        var llaves= Object.keys(rows)
        var valores= Object.values(rows)
        for ( el of llaves)
          {
            console.log(el)
            var llaves2=Object.keys(rows[el])
            console.log(llaves2)
            for (el2 of llaves2){
              var elementop=rows[el][el2]
              document.querySelector("#cons_res").textContent+=elementop
            } 
          }
      }
      else
        {
          console.log('Error while performing Query.');
          console.log(err);
        }
    });

    connection.end();
    }
}
```

Si pudieran orientarme, ya que soy nueva en esto de programación o si mi duda no está bien, se los agradecería.

Saludos.

Comment: Creo que te faltaron conceptos que aprender. No tengo una respuesta a tu pregunta porque ni siquiera la entiendo, y me parece que tu problema es mas conceptual. Necesitas php para conectarte a una db? **NO**. Hay montones de lenguajes de backend para conectarte a una db. Vas a poder desde el frontend? **NO** y no deberias tampoco. Tu db tiene que estar protegida siempre. Mongo es un motor de DB NO SQL. Tambien hay montones de otros motores NO SQL y SQL. podes conectarte al que quieras. Y ese codigo donde lo estarias ejecutando?

Comment: cual es el problema?

Comment: Php es un lenguaje que se interpreta en un servidor, como hay otros que también lo hacen y estos permiten una conexión con una DB, no puedes conectarte a una DB desde tu browser. De acuerdo a [esta arquitectura](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_YRC0IbufbRc/ScQGwiTIEoI/AAAAAAAAABI/XSScKzIpWkk/s320/bdd-images-basecs.gif), tu browser es el cliente el cual hará una petición al servidor(digamos tu implementación en php u otro lenguaje de servidor), este servidor se comunicará con la base de datos y el servidor le dará una respuesta a tu browser(cliente).

Comment: ¿Por qué has escrito un código JS? Si piensas ejecutarlo en el _frontend_ (o sea en nu navegador web) no es buena idea como te han dicho. Si piensas ejecutarlo en el backend, con node.js ¿para qué? Si todo lo que necesitas es conectar "directamente" con la base de datos, sin intermediarios, y enviar comandos SQL, ¿por qué no usas el cliente de línea de comandos [`mysql`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html)?

Comment: Creo que tal vez deberias explicarnos que queres hacer y porque pensaste que esta era la forma de hacerlo...

Comment: Lo que trato de hacer es que los datos de la tabla que tengo en mi DB aparezcan en una tabla que estará en mi aplicación, y que yo pueda agregar más datos a la tabla de mi aplicación y que estos se agreguen a la tabla de la DB. Y que los datos de ambas tablas se puedan editar o eliminar pero desde mi aplicación.

Comment: Cuando dices **mi aplicación**, te refieres a: ¿una aplicación de escritorio?, ¿una aplicación web? o ¿exactamente a qué aplicación?. Empieza aclarando las cosas. En las etiquetas de tu pregunta pones `nodejs`, `javascript`, `html`. Me imagino que tienes una aplicación web. Por lo tanto, ¿tienes alguna tecnología basada en `nodejs` para el backend? ¿Cuál?. Por el hecho de usar la librería o paquete `mysql2`, intuyo que tu aplicación es un servidor corriendo sobre `nodejs`. No podemos ayudar mucho sin saber exactamente dónde estamos parados. Saludos